# Why does this recursive function continue to be called after the base case appears to be met?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include <iostream>                 

void myFunction(int counter);

int main(){
    myFunction(4);
}

void myFunction( int counter)
{
    if(counter == 0)
        return;
    else
       {
           std::cout << "hello" << counter << std::endl;
           myFunction(--counter); //function call
           std::cout << counter<< "X" << std::endl;
           return;
       }
}
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
hello4
hello3
hello2
hello1
0x
1x
2x
3x
```

It looks to me like after "hello1" is printed the counter should go down to 0, and so the if(counter == 0) statement should be met and the function should end. Why doesn't it?

Comment: The base case returns, and then its caller continues. It prints the `X` stuff after the recursive call returns.

Comment: To understand how functions like this work, pretend you're the computer and execute the function by hand, keeping track of all the variables on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 4):

try to follow the calls using indentation.

- call myFunction(4)

  - print "hello4"
  - call myFunction(3)

    - print "hello3"
    - call myFunction(2)

      - print "hello2"
      - call myFunction(1)

        - print "hello1"
        - call myFunction(0)

          - return
        - print 0x
        - return
      - print 1x
      - return
    - print 2x
    - return
  - print 3x
  - return

Comment: @franji1 included the return statements as per your request

Answer (score 2):

The output that confuses you:

```
hello1
0x
```

is caused by these lines:

```
std::cout << "hello" << counter << std::endl;
myFunction(--counter); //function call
std::cout << counter<< "X" << std::endl;
```

when `counter` is `1`, it:

- outputs `hello1`
- calls `myFunction(0)`
- and outputs `0x`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the control flow works. Lets simplify the function and just test `myFunction(1)`:

```
---myFunction(1)--
prints hello1
executes myFunction(0)
    ---myFunction(0)--
    returns
prints 1X
returns
```

The way to solve this problem is to do `return myFunction(--counter);`

Answer (score 1):

When you call a recursive function, it will create a stack frame for that function, and continue creating stack frames for each call.

These stack frames will store the state of each call until it return.

The first call will create a stack frame where `counter = 4`. It will then decrement the counter and call the function again, creating a new stack frame, while retaining the old one on the stack. This continues until the base case is reached.

Once the base case returns, then the caller of the base case will execute the next instruction (after the function call which resulted in the base case), which is to print the value of `counter` that it had stored in its stack frame. After printing, it will then return, and *its* caller will print the value it had stored.

Comment: Thank you, I had been under the impression that a return statement meant to stop calling the function.

Comment: @user3525627, The return statement means to stop calling the *current instance* of the function. But recursion creates *multiple instances* of the function.

Answer (score 1):

It does end. Remember that at the end of the recursion that the stack will unwind. You have the `std::cout << counter<< "X" << std::endl;` call at the end of each "loop". That's probably where you're getting confused. You can see the "Hello" print out as it gets into each step and then the "x" after that step.

Look at the next to last iteration. Print "hello1", call `myfunction(0)`, print "0x" and then return. Each step in the recursion does this.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion logic is actually working.  Its your output that's broken.  The fact that it fails to print `4x` should be a hint.

The problem is you're decrementing the counter when you pass it into the recursion call and *then* printing it.

Try replacing

```
myFunction(--counter)
```

with

```
myFunction(counter - 1)
```

and you should get the output you expect.

You can avoid this kind of error by making your recursion counter a const value, so that you can't accidentally modify it within the call.

```
void myFunction(const int counter)
```